# How to efficiently implement dynamic time warping with early abandoning in Python for large multidimensional datasets?

Tags: python, performance, optimization, parallel-processing, time-series

I'm working on a time series analysis project in Python where I have to compare large multidimensional datasets. I've found that Dynamic Time Warping (DTW) is an effective method for measuring the similarity between two sequences, considering possible time shifts and local scaling. However, I'm struggling with optimizing the DTW algorithm for my large datasets, and I've discovered that early abandoning could be a potential solution to speed up the process.

Here's a basic implementation of the DTW algorithm I'm currently using:

```
import numpy as np

def euclidean_distance(x, y):
    return np.sqrt(np.sum((x - y) ** 2))

def dtw(x, y, dist_func):
    len_x, len_y = len(x), len(y)
    dtw_matrix = np.zeros((len_x + 1, len_y + 1))
    dtw_matrix[1:, 0] = np.inf
    dtw_matrix[0, 1:] = np.inf

    for i in range(1, len_x + 1):
        for j in range(1, len_y + 1):
            cost = dist_func(x[i - 1], y[j - 1])
            dtw_matrix[i, j] = cost + min(dtw_matrix[i - 1, j], dtw_matrix[i, j - 1], dtw_matrix[i - 1, j - 1])

    return dtw_matrix[len_x, len_y]
```

My datasets are large, and each data point has multiple dimensions. I want to integrate early abandoning into this implementation to significantly reduce the computational time without sacrificing accuracy.

- What's the most efficient way to implement early abandoning in the DTW algorithm for large multidimensional datasets in Python?
- How can I parallelize this implementation to further improve performance, considering I have multiple dataset pairs to compare?
- What are the best libraries that can help achieve better performance while using DTW for my specific use case?

Comment: What is the dimensionality of each point in practice? Can you also specify what do you mean by "early abandoning" in this specific context? Besides, regarding libraries, not that *"seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, etc."* is off-topic on Stack-Overflow.

Comment: @JérômeRichard by early abandoning I meant to speed up the computation by abandoning the calculation of the DTW distance for a given pair of sequences when it's highly likely that the distance will be greater than a specified threshold or the best distance found so far.

Comment: Ok. Ins't that just a conditional to add in the two nested for loop?

Comment: And what about the dimensionality of each point? (in the first comment)

Comment: You tried of course [this package](https://dtaidistance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/dtw.html) which has implemented early stopping and data can be multidimensional?